Why is there no central heating flow through radiator pipework?
I live in a house in London, UK with central heating based on 2 zone valves with 1 serving ground floor and 1 serving upstairs.
I was putting up a picture light in the lounge and with a 20mm holesaw, I drilled a 6mm pilot hole right into the centre of the 10mm polypipe feeding the radiator below resulting in hot water flying across the room.
I called out an emergency plumber and he cut out the plaster board and pipe and then I
fitted a speedfit equal coupler (with inserts) once parts were delivered the following morning.
Once done I re-pressurised the filling loop to 2 bar but have been unable to get any hot water to flow downstairs and none of the 4 radiators are working. Upstairs is all working fine.
I have had 2 different plumbers out now but no-one is able to diagnose and a 3rd plumber is coming tomorrow.
It almost seems that where I drilled, perhaps this has somehow entered the pipework and caused a blockage and the installation has been piped in series rather than parallel and there is no route for water to flow as I can't see why all radiators are off, but surely that can't be the case? The zone valve is plumbed in with 22mm copper but the rads are in 10mm polypipe.
The plumbers have replaced the zone valve but still no change. They used a thermal imaging camera but weren't able to identify the issue either. There seems to be a lot of head scratching and I'm concerned whether to let them keep investigating while paying hourly or contact my insurers.
Would a powerflush be the next step and if so, what is risk of this blowing speedfit fittings?
What else can I ask them to look at?
To make matters worse, we've just had the rooms re-painted.
Thanks

Did you make sure to bleed the system after repair to make sure there was no air trapped in the piping or radiators that would prevent your water from flowing?

What did they see with the thermal camera? That should make it abundantly clear where the water is flowing, and once you identify the obstruction you'll know what needs to be fixed.

Yes, we have bled the system. The plumber today thinks there could be an airlock as the pipes run up then across the ceiling void so either an airlock that needs pushing through or a blockage caused potentially by a kink when pulling the pipe down to access it where we installed the speedfit coupler. Hopefully it is the former and he is coming back next week.

The thermal camera only really worked showing either side of the zone valve. Couldn't really see anything behind the plasterboard. Not sure how good these cameras are?
